# How does Google Calendar API's Sync Token work with different request filters (timeMin, timeMax) for each request?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

The goal of my app is to keep a synchronized copy of the Google users' calendars and events for the **past 7 days and next 7 days**.

I.E, every time it performs calendar/events queries against the Google API, `TimeMin` is set to `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(-7)` and `TimeMax` is set to `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(7)` (C# here as example).

Right now, I perform full syncs using the above filters each time, and compare the result sets against the local copy. New events are added, updated events are updated, unchanged events are untouched.

Notably for deletions, I have set `ShowDeleted` to `false` on Google side, so the remote results do not contain deleted events, and therefore I can tell which events should be deleted by comparison. Because the `TimeMin` and `TimeMax` filters are constantly shifting with each sync, the events that go "out of scope" due to their times naturally do not show up in the remote result set and are therefore deleted from the local copy.

I wonder in this case, is it even worth it to use `syncToken` for incremental sync, and if so, how would it work with the shifting `timeMin` and `timeMax` for every single request?

Comment: please edit your question and include [example] and describe any issues you are having with your current solution.  Are you using https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push?

Comment: I assume you are sending your full sync request on a daily basis. Since your datetime filters are also changing on a daily basis, the only case you might want to use incremental sync is to update the changes occurred on the same day you sent your full sync request. Example you sent a full sync request at 00:01 midnight, then you can send incremental sync request every 1 hr to keep your calendars updated. I hope you get my point.

Comment: Another option you might consider is to do a full sync of 1 month duration, then get the incremental sync daily using your datetime filter

Comment: @RonM I do sync hourly throughout the day, additionally I have change notification configured – but my research shows Google's notification cannot be depended on to cover all events, but instead it's an invitation for "sync now", hence me wanting to know if it's worth it to do incremental sync or "full" sync each time I get the notification.

Comment: @RonM Note that my "past 7 days and next 7 days" are rolling based on the current instantaneous timestamps, not something like midnight to midnight UTC, so even my syncs throughout the same day will all have different filters. I'd assume that makes syncToken non-viable? Since I'm only syncing 14 days of events anyway, I'd assume it shouldn't be bad in terms of efficacy to perform "full" sync each time?

Comment: Yes, I thought your filter just adjust its date having similar filter daily. But since you pointed out that it changes even on the same day, there's no benefit in using incremental sync. I advised you stick with your full sync request instead.